# Mysql2 not part of the bundle - but it is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

Rails 4.1.5, capistrano 3 trying to deploy to ubuntu.

Get the following errors on deploy:

```
Gem::LoadError: mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile
```

But mysql2 is in the Gemfile.  I've tried delete the shared/bundle directory to force redo of gem installs, but doesn't fix.

What's going on here?  Why doesn't it see the mysql2 in the Gemfile?

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.5'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'coffeebeans'
gem 'friendly_id', '5.0.3'
gem 'dumper'
gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 4.0.2"
gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 4.0.0"
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-validation-rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'
gem 'paperclip', '4.1.1'
gem 'slim'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn-table', '0.1.0'
gem 'axlsx_rails'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.0.2'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'i18n-active_record',
    :git => 'git://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record.git',
    :require => 'i18n/active_record'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'thin'
end

group :development do
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  gem 'powder'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'capistrano-rails',   '~> 1.1', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'spring-commands-testunit'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.2'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'faker'
end
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record.git
  revision: 2d9a22b6a4e5d809782cdbfa65b14d9e47aa27fc
  specs:
    i18n-active_record (0.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.5.0)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.5)
      actionpack (= 4.1.5)
      actionview (= 4.1.5)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.5)
      actionview (= 4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.5)
      activemodel (= 4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.5)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.3.6)
    ansi (1.4.3)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    axlsx (2.0.1)
      htmlentities (~> 4.3.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.1)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0.0)
    axlsx_rails (0.2.1)
      axlsx (>= 2.0.1)
      rails (>= 3.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
      bcrypt (>= 3.1.3)
    builder (3.2.2)
    capistrano (3.2.1)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.3)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rbenv (2.0.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capybara (2.4.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    capybara-webkit (1.3.0)
      capybara (>= 2.0.2, < 2.5.0)
      json
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cliver (0.3.2)
    cocaine (0.5.4)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    coffeebeans (1.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      coffee-script
    colorize (0.7.3)
    daemons (1.1.9)
    dalli (2.7.2)
    database_cleaner (1.2.0)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    dumper (1.6.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0)
      multipart-post (>= 1.1.5)
      posix-spawn (>= 0.3.6)
    dynamic_form (1.1.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.3)
    execjs (2.2.1)
    factory_girl (4.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.4.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.4.3)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    friendly_id (5.0.3)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hirb (0.7.2)
    htmlentities (4.3.2)
    i18n (0.6.11)
    jquery-rails (3.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    jquery-validation-rails (1.12.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.8.1)
    launchy (2.4.2)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    letter_opener (1.2.0)
      launchy (~> 2.2)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    metaclass (0.0.4)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.0)
    minitest (5.4.1)
    minitest-reporters (1.0.5)
      ansi
      builder
      minitest (>= 5.0)
      ruby-progressbar
    mocha (1.1.0)
      metaclass (~> 0.0.1)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.16)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.9.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.3.1)
      mini_portile (= 0.6.0)
    paperclip (4.1.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
      mime-types
    pdf-core (0.2.5)
    poltergeist (1.5.1)
      capybara (~> 2.1)
      cliver (~> 0.3.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.2.0)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    posix-spawn (0.3.9)
    powder (0.2.1)
      thor (>= 0.11.5)
    prawn (1.2.1)
      pdf-core (~> 0.2.5)
      ttfunk (~> 1.2.0)
    prawn-table (0.1.0)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-mini-profiler (0.9.2)
      rack (>= 1.1.3)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.5)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.5)
      actionpack (= 4.1.5)
      actionview (= 4.1.5)
      activemodel (= 4.1.5)
      activerecord (= 4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.5)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.1.5)
      actionpack (= 4.1.5)
      activesupport (= 4.1.5)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.3.2)
    redcarpet (3.1.2)
    rspec-core (3.1.2)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.1.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.1.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-rails (3.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.1.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.1.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.1.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-support (3.1.0)
    ruby-progressbar (1.5.1)
    rubyzip (1.0.0)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    simple_form (3.0.2)
      actionpack (~> 4.0)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
    slim (2.0.3)
      temple (~> 0.6.6)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    slim-rails (2.1.5)
      actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.2)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 4.2)
      slim (~> 2.0)
    spring (1.1.3)
    spring-commands-rspec (1.0.2)
      spring (>= 0.9.1)
    spring-commands-testunit (1.0.1)
      spring (>= 0.9.1)
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.1.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sshkit (1.5.1)
      colorize
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    temple (0.6.8)
    thin (1.6.2)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    ttfunk (1.2.2)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    websocket-driver (0.3.4)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  axlsx_rails
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.1.2)
  capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
  capistrano-rails (~> 1.1)
  capistrano-rbenv
  capybara
  capybara-webkit
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  coffeebeans
  dalli
  database_cleaner (= 1.2)
  dumper
  dynamic_form
  factory_girl_rails (~> 4.0)
  faker
  friendly_id (= 5.0.3)
  hirb
  i18n-active_record!
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  jquery-validation-rails
  launchy
  letter_opener
  minitest
  minitest-reporters
  mocha
  mysql2
  paperclip (= 4.1.1)
  poltergeist
  powder
  prawn
  prawn-table (= 0.1.0)
  rack-mini-profiler
  rails (= 4.1.5)
  redcarpet
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.2)
  simple_form (~> 3.0.2)
  slim
  slim-rails
  spring
  spring-commands-rspec
  spring-commands-testunit
  thin
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

Comment: Have you tried putting mysql2 under production group?

Comment: Can you ssh to your server and try `bundle show mysql2` from app root?

Comment: `bundle show mysql2` returns `Could not find minitest-5.4.1 in any of the sources`.  No idea what's going on there....

Comment: Add mysql2 to production didn't make a difference.

Comment: @croceldon you need to update your bundler `gem update bundler` and after that `bundle install`. Then let me know output of `bundle show mysql2`

Comment: Here was my issue - I'd originally but the wrong git repo in the cap 3 deploy.rb file.  Even after correcting, it seemed to be stuck on that repo, which didn't have the mysql2 gem in it.  I had to delete the repo directory on the server, then cap production deploy - all worked good then.